# Send emails to all approvers when a approval is rejected

Tags: approval-process

Is there a way in the approval to only send emails to to approvers when an approval request has been rejected?
This should only be sent to the people who are in the approval path and maybe they had approved before.
Also, please consider the option of where the approver is manually chosen and not just the static assigned approver.

Thanks.

Comment: for manual selection of approvers in approval process, the approval process should be implemented using apex.